# Sublime Text 2 - Html Autocomplete issue

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

this is my first question so pardon me for my noob. I used to put html + TAB in Sublime Text and the result was:

```
<html>  
   <head>  
     <title>
     </title>  
   </head> 
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

now the result is only

```
<html></html>
```

Maybe i did something wrong, i have installed emmet and three js packages. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely multiple snippets/completions installed that use the same trigger `html`. You have two options to resolve this:

1. Type `html`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. This will show the completion selector, which allows you to select which snippet/completion to trigger.

**Example:**

[image]

2. Alternatively, you can force the completion selector to show whenever working on HTML files (it's disabled by default). Open your user preferences (Preferences > Settings User) and adjust the `auto_complete_selector` by adding the `text.html` scope (or the more limited `text.html.basic`).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you installed Emmet. <kbd>tab</kbd> key is now used by Emmet to expand [abbreviations](http://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/).

You can use `!` instead of `html` and press <kbd>tab</kbd>. Also you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> if you want the old behavior.